# Convert PDF to HTML using iText library

Tags: java, html, itext

Can we convert PDF to HTML file using iText library in java? I have converted html to pdf and want to achieve PDF to HTML using iText. I don't want to use two different libraries for same operation, hence avoiding to use pdfBox.

Comment: Short answer is No

Comment: Indeed. Flagging as duplicate.